# How to scatter plot 2d array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, plot

How do you plot a scatter plot for an array `result_array` of shape `(1087, 2)` that looks like this:

```
array([[-1.89707840e+03,  3.99819932e+00],
       [-2.55018840e+03, -2.61913223e+00],
       [-1.85480840e+03, -2.36545732e-01],
       ...,
       [-1.64432840e+03,  9.79555441e+00],
       [-1.59022840e+03,  1.08955493e+01],
       [-1.73963840e+03,  3.60132161e-01]])
```

?

---

Update:

Tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(result_array[:, 0], result_array[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

and the plot looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the array is `X`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

`plt.scatter()` has many addional options, see the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) for details.

**Answer to the updated question:**

It seems that you have an outlier row in the array with the first coordinate close to 2.5*10^6 (which gives the point close to the right margin of the plot), while other rows have their first coordinates smaller by a few orders of magnitude. For example, the rows in the part of the array visible in the question have first coordinates close to -2000. For this reason, these rows are squished into what looks like a vertical line in the plot.

There are two possible ways to fix it:

1. If you really have only one (or just a few) outliers, you can remove them from the array and possibly plot them separately.
2. Alternatively, if you want to plot all points at once, then using the logarithmic scale on the x-axis may help. Since you have some points with negative first coordinates, you would need to use the symmetric logarithmic scale - which is logarithmic in both positive and negative directions of the x-axis.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
plt.xscale('symlog')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi bb1, thanks for your answer but the plot returned looks kind of weird? Please see question update:)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I removed the outlier and the graph makes more sense now. But I removed the outlier by converting the array into a pandas DataFrame, ie,. `result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_array)
result_df1 = result_df[result_df[0] < 100000]`. Is there a way to do it directly from the array?

Comment: @nilsinelabore Yes, you can use numpy in a similar way: `results = result_array[result_array[:,0] < 10**5]`.

Comment: Thank you. And I assume to consider both columns, we could use `results = result_array[(result_array[:,0] < 10**5) & (result_array[:,1] < 10**5)]` ?